# Mount an active logical volume results in special device does not exist

Tags: ubuntu, windows-11, lvm, wsl2

I'm trying to get data from an Ubuntu server disk that got it's boot partition faulted.

On the disk there is a logical volume that I'm trying to access through WSL2 on Windows 11.

I can activate the volume but then de LV path is not present in /dev

```
dev@Develop:/mnt$ sudo mount /dev/DockerHost-vg/root /mnt/dh/root
mount: /mnt/dh/root: special device /dev/DockerHost-vg/root does not exist.
```

I'm no Linux expert so maybe I'm forgetting something? Any ideas?

```
dev@Develop:/mnt$ sudo lvdisplay
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/DockerHost-vg/root
  LV Name                root
  VG Name                DockerHost-vg
  LV UUID                uWyuke-bvSk-XIsR-P8so-zom3-2CG8-DildMz
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time DockerHost, 2018-03-18 14:04:19 +0100
  LV Status              available
  # open                 0
  LV Size                206.89 GiB
  Current LE             52964
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:0

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/DockerHost-vg/swap_1
  LV Name                swap_1
  VG Name                DockerHost-vg
  LV UUID                V8wHIS-Nh3t-JbUw-FlDQ-Ar7C-NQ2w-OSkn5B
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time DockerHost, 2018-03-18 14:04:19 +0100
  LV Status              available
  # open                 0
  LV Size                <15.70 GiB
  Current LE             4018
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:1

dev@Develop:/mnt$ sudo vgdisplay
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               DockerHost-vg
  System ID
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  5
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                2
  Open LV               0
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               <222.59 GiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              56983
  Alloc PE / Size       56982 / <222.59 GiB
  Free  PE / Size       1 / 4.00 MiB
  VG UUID               DLU937-9PZA-6x8O-bKJJ-m6HU-nRWo-DGKqMG

dev@Develop:/mnt$ sudo mount /dev/DockerHost-vg/root /mnt/dh/root
mount: /mnt/dh/root: special device /dev/DockerHost-vg/root does not exist.

dev@Develop:/mnt$ lsblk -f
NAME   FSTYPE LABEL UUID FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINT
loop0                          0   100% /mnt/wsl/docker-desktop/cli-tools
loop1
sda
sdb                       238.1G     0% /mnt/wsl/docker-desktop/docker-desktop-user-distro
sdc                       203.2G    14% /mnt/wsl/docker-desktop-data/isocache
sdd                         237G     0% /
sde
├─sde1
├─sde2
└─sde3

dev@Develop:/mnt$ sudo dmsetup ls -o blkdevname
DockerHost--vg-root     (dm-0)
DockerHost--vg-swap_1   (dm-1)
```

Comment: Does `lsblk -f` show any relevant devices (possibly named `/dev/dm-###`)? WSL2 runs the entire distro in a container, so udev might not be creating the named symlinks correctly... if WSL2 even runs udev at all.

Comment: I added the results of the lsblk command to the question. It returns the partitions on the source disk as /sde#

Comment: `sudo dmsetup ls -o blkdevname`?

Comment: It returns 2 devices, I added the command to the original question.
DockerHost--vg-root     (dm-0)
DockerHost--vg-swap_1   (dm-1)

Comment: Oh, I got it, thanks to @TomYan.
I needed to use the dm-# id mapped in /dev/dm-# to mount the volume. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: @BjornBailleul Would you mind sharing how you solved it as an answer post to this question? Thanks

Comment: The problem was not solved. The disk was lost.